# Failed installing pylint via cmd (Windows)

Tags: python, pip, pylint

As the title says, I'm trying to install pylint with the below command:

`pip install pylint`

But I get the below exception:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2482, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2344, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1265, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2508, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2583, in scan_list
    "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'lazy-object-proxy ==1.4.*', 'at', '*')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Haiss\pip\pip.log
```

Anybody have any ideas what's causing it to fail? I have Python 3 installed using Anaconda. I checked the debug log but it doesn't provide any additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
easy_install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Mostly worked! But now I'm getting an error saying "colorama requires a different Python". Is there way to uninstall or bypass this? I tried running pip uninstall colorama but it isn't working

Comment: Never mind using easy install for everything seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.